# What is the performance impact of using a Match All filter in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

As part of query optimization for a project, I'm considering replacing a date range filter (cached and is returning everything like match all) with a [match all filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-filter.html). I'm wondering if this will improve performance?

My assumption is that upon execution the system would simply ignore this filter and I can get improvements in memory usage (removed the cached filter) as well as some execution time. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends on what are you going to do with the results. Replacing a date range with match all will increase the number of results elasticsearch will have to process, which might cause more slowdown than you will gain from removing the filter.

Comment: the range filter I want to replace essentially gets everything (date_min_possible to date_max_possible)

Comment: I think I also need to specify that this is in context of elastic search 1.7 as 2.0 does not have a distinction between filters and queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging into the source code for elastic 1.7, I found my answer -

A Match_All filter has **RAM usage of size of int** and it simply **returns a bitset of the size of maxdocId** parameter (i.e. number of records). 
No requirement to cache this was an additional plus point.

This bitset should be the same as that generated by range filter under the assumption that all records did have the field on which range was applied (which was the case for me).

Note: Answer provided by imotov was a starting point, but I'm adding mine for complete details.

*References:*

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/1.7/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsFilter.java

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/1.7/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/lucene/docset/AllDocIdSet.java

Answer (score 1):

If this filter matches most or all records, removing it is definitely a good optimization. However, the memory benefits might be smaller than you expect, since filters that match all records are quite optimized.

Comment: I'm more looking about replacing with MatchAll filter, does that provide any improvement compared to case where date range that results in all records?
For all other cases, I need to retain the date range filter in there.

Comment: Yes, it does because your date range is essentially a filter that checks that the date field is present and it might cause some overhead especially if you have some records that don't have the date field. However, it would be even better to remove it completely instead of replacing it with match all.